# How to make an Overlay like Tango message received bubble

Tags: android

If you receive a message on Tango in Android, you can view a bubble overlay on top of any app you may open.  Clicking the View component allows you to move it.

How do you create that overlay ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my tutorial here :

http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/05/facebook-chat-heads-feature.html

http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/06/chat-heads-v2.html

That should do it ! help